# Простой 2D движок для рисования

Tags: 2d, c++

Привет всем.
Можете подсказать простой движок на C++ для рисования прямых, вывода текста и тому подобных фишек. С открытым кодом, естественно. Нужно лишь рисование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону QT библиотек - например [QPainter class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html)
Там очень подробная документация с примерами, и есть все вам необходимое
Например вот описание многоугольника:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.
Я думаю вы имели в виду не движок, а мультимедийную библиотеку.
Могу предложить вам посмотреть в сторону [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).
Она написана на С++ и очень проста в освоении.

P.S. Хотя наверно если вам чисто для рисования линий то она слишком много лишнего содержит в себе.

Comment: Линии, примитивы разные, в основном прямоугольники и текст. Делаю курсач и надо как-то отрисовывать обозначения микросхем, а на Windows Forms делать не хочется. Спасибо за предложение.

Comment: А не проще тогда взять какой нибудь редактор электросхем и там нарисовать все что нужно?

Comment: Так курсач в том и состоит, что надо создать редактор электросхем.